# how to save the get the changes in listpreference?

Tags: android, xml, sharedpreferences, listpreference

I want to let the user choose the font size on my app. how can I react to his selections? how can I get the value from his selection?
thanks
I have this code of the preferences:

```
<string-array name="aaa_entries">
    <item >0</item>
    <item >1</item>
    <item >2</item>
    <item >3</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="aaa_values">
    <item >Very small text</item>
    <item >Small text</item>
    <item >Normal text</item>
    <item >Large text</item>
</string-array>
```

Code:

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    if (key.equals("pref_sync")) {
        String selectedFont=sharedPreferences.getString("pref_sync",null);
        if("Very small text".equalsIgnoreCase(selectedFont)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"asdasdasdasd",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `listener` to the `ListPreference`, and when user select an item from the `ListPreference` , `onPreferenceChange` will be called with the new value selected.

```
Preference listPreference = getPreferenceManager().findPreference("your_key");

listPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                String userSelectedValue = (String) newValue;
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), “user picked a font”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```